# win32 Automatically Size a parent Window to Fit Its Content

Tags: c++, winapi

I  created a class which generate windows  and i want the size of windows   changes to fit the content in it.

for example I have a selection window which contains total of 7 combobox and radio buttons in (4 lines) but the window generated is far too big for the content in it.

I want the parent window's size to shrink automatically to fit the content of the child windows in it. if I added more content, i want it to become bigger without manually setting the size of the window

```
CreateWindowEx(
        dwExStyle, ClassName(), lpWindowName, dwStyle, x, y,
        nWidth, nHeight, hWndParent, hMenu, GetModuleHandle(NULL), this
    );
```

I am using `CW_USEDEFAULT` for width and height

Comment: Win32 contains nothing to do this for you automatically. You need to handle sizing manually. Keep track of the controls on the form, what their extent is. When you know where they all are, resize the window to match. Also, don't use `GetModuleHandle(NULL)` here, pass the instance of the module which is given to you in your `WinMain`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan ah Okay thanks. but shouldn't i use GetModuleHandle(NULL) if i am creating it in a base template class inside a dll?

Comment: OK, my assumption is that the module handle that you pass here identifies the module in which the code resides. That's the normal approach. The module handle is used to identify the window class. For instance, if multiple DLLs register window classes with the same name, then this is how the system selects the window class. Now, if you are registering the window class in one module, and creating the window in a different module, then I can understand your code.

Comment: Very, very brittle. If you are registering window classes in a module for use in a different module, at the very least make sure to have the registrant provide the correct module handle. Better yet, provide a window factory, and keep the module handle internal to the module that registered the window classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no parameter setting to automatically modify the parent window size. Instead, you need to set up your own in the parent window:

1. Get the `WM_PARENTNOTIFY` message from the child window(make sure child window doesn't have the `WS_EX_NOPARENTNOTIFY` extended window style), then determine whether it is a create(`lParam = WM_CREATE`) or destroy(`lParam = WM_DESTROY`) message.
2. Calculate window size.

Here is a simple resize code:

```
// WindowsProject11.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "WindowsProject11.h"
#include <vector>
#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100
#define MIN(x,y) ((x)<(y)?(x):(y))
#define MAX(x,y) ((x)>(y)?(x):(y))
// Global Variables:
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // current instance
WCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // The title bar text
WCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // the main window class name

// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // TODO: Place code here.

    // Initialize global strings
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_WINDOWSPROJECT11, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // Perform application initialization:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_WINDOWSPROJECT11));
    MSG msg;

    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}



//
//  FUNCTION: MyRegisterClass()
//
//  PURPOSE: Registers the window class.
//
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_WINDOWSPROJECT11));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDC_WINDOWSPROJECT11);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
}

//
//   FUNCTION: InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int)
//
//   PURPOSE: Saves instance handle and creates main window
//
//   COMMENTS:
//
//        In this function, we save the instance handle in a global variable and
//        create and display the main program window.
//
std::vector<HWND> btns;
RECT minRect;
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

   HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, 200, 60, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);//create a minimum size window
   GetWindowRect(hWnd,&minRect);
   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);

   return TRUE;
}

//
//  FUNCTION: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  PURPOSE:  Processes messages for the main window.
//
//  WM_COMMAND  - process the application menu
//  WM_PAINT    - Paint the main window
//  WM_DESTROY  - post a quit message and return
//
//
RECT childRect = { 0 };
BOOL first = true;

BOOL CALLBACK EnumChildProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (hwnd == (HWND)lParam)
        return true;
    if (first)
    {
        first = false;
        GetWindowRect(hwnd,&childRect);
        return true;
    }
    RECT rect;
    GetWindowRect(hwnd,&rect);
    childRect.right = MAX(childRect.right, rect.right);
    childRect.bottom = MAX(childRect.bottom, rect.bottom);
    return true;
}
int i = 20;
int index = 0;
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
            HWND btn;
            // Parse the menu selections:
            switch (wmId)
            {
            case IDM_ABOUT:
                DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
                break;
            case IDM_EXIT:
                DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                break;
            case ID_FILE_CREATEBUTTON:
                btn = CreateWindow(L"BUTTON", L"this is a button", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | BS_FLAT, 0, i, 200, 80, hWnd, (HMENU)2, hInst, NULL);
                btns.push_back(btn);
                i += 100;
                break;
            case ID_FILE_DESTORYLAST:
                DestroyWindow(btns.back());
                btns.pop_back();
                break;
            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }
        break;
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            // TODO: Add any drawing code that uses hdc here...
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    case WM_PARENTNOTIFY:
    {
        int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
        HWND hwnd;
        RECT cRect;
        RECT Rect = { 0 };
        switch (wmId)
        {
        case WM_CREATE:
            hwnd = (HWND)lParam;
            GetWindowRect(hwnd, &cRect);
            GetWindowRect(hWnd, &Rect);
            Rect.right = MAX(Rect.right, cRect.right + 7);//Windows 10 has thin invisible borders on left, right, and bottom
            Rect.bottom = MAX(Rect.bottom, cRect.bottom + 7);
            SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, Rect.right - Rect.left, Rect.bottom - Rect.top, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            EnumChildWindows(hWnd, EnumChildProc,lParam);
            Rect.left = minRect.left;
            Rect.top = minRect.top;
            Rect.right = MAX(minRect.right, childRect.right + 7);
            Rect.bottom = MAX(minRect.bottom, childRect.bottom + 7);
            SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, Rect.right - Rect.left, Rect.bottom - Rect.top, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
            first = true;
            break;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

// Message handler for about box.
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

I have added 2 menus in the window. For the whole project, please reference to this [link](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AuuE71XVcHDogk-bDnUUq9dVO5tM).